# Sql Server Management Studio USE statement equivalent in MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, ssms

In *Sql Server Management Studio* we could run query on a selected database using the `USE` statement. Is there an equivalent for this function in MySql?

The problem is, I would like to run a query on `Information Schema`:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'campaign'
```

But in my program, all I have is a connection string and not the database name. If I am to use the above query under a specific database, I should first parse my connection string and look for the database name there and then change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM databasename.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'campaign'
```

On Sql Server the first query only returned a result on my connection string to my destination database but here in MySql the first query apparently looks for the table in all databases and that is not what I want.

Comment: The equivalent of MS SQL Server's `USE` in MySQL is [`USE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/use.html).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL also has `USE`.

```
USE db1;
```

Documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Update: After re-reading your question, it seems like you might not actually want `USE`, but that you want to filter your results to a specific schema:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'campaign'
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databasename'
```

Comment: Which means I should parse my connection string to get the database name.

Comment: @Pedram Yeah seems that's the best option.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear from [the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html), but the `TABLE_SCHEMA` field in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` has the database name in MySQL.  This is because in MySQL, [schema and database are synonymous](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_schema) even so far that [`CREATE SCHEMA` is a synonym to `CREATE DATABASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-database.html).

If that doesn't work for you, one alternative is the [`SHOW TABLES` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-tables.html).